# How the saml2 logout request url in wso2is

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

We have logout Request Object from the java and we don't have the cookie session index value but we have the session index coming from SAML2 assertion XML coming from wso2Is ,So by using the session Index and logout Request how can i post by using the ajax call or any rest-client.

Can any one provide me the URL of logout request how it will be?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [blog post](http://xacmlinfo.org/2013/06/28/how-saml2-single-logout-works/). It provides steps you should follow. 
Basically you need to create the SAMLogoutRequest as below,

```
<saml2p:logoutrequest xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" id="flkjhgfehcfjkjjmabgkcmlcnalbcillibfeeeag" issueinstant="2013-06-28T11:51:06.024Z" notonorafter="2013-06-28T11:56:06.024Z" reason="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:logout:user" version="2.0">
  <saml2:nameid xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity">admin</saml2:nameid>
  <saml2p:sessionindex>26C0530CBEA1DCF404C95B029D6A64AF</saml2p:sessionindex>
</saml2p:logoutrequest>
```

and send a POST to https://localhost:9443/samlsso (which is the saml sso logout endpoint by default)

Comment: How can i pass the SAMLLogoutRequest as a body or as a paramenter for the request URL .I have tried in both ways by passing in the body i am getting the response as in wso2Is console is 
  "Query string : null " and when i am passing as a parameter by converting the xml to base64 encoded value i am getting the below error " Element type "saml2:nameid" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>"."

Answer (score 0):

You could use https://localhost:9443/samlsso?slo=true&spEntityID=travelocity.com&returnTo=https://localhost:8080/avs.com/slo Get reqeust for logout.